# Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://): failed to open stream

Tags: 7, files

I get this message from Drupal:

> Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://file8vyLsO): failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (line 1900 of /home/donatelo/public_html/thenameofthesite.com/includes/file.inc).
>
> The file could not be created.

I don't know what I did to cause this, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure your temporary folder exists and is writeable.

See the file system settings at:

`admin/config/media/file-system`

Comment: Thanks, already did it. Actually, I erased my old path, from WAMP, before site was uploaded, and it works ok now. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The error happens, because your temporary directory is not writable by your web server user.

Check for details in *Status report* at: `/admin/reports/status`

If you're using `drush`, this may fix it:

```
drush vset file_temporary_path /tmp
```